# Is Full Outer Join Not Supported in Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0?

Tags: sql, outer-join, oledbdataadapter

I am querying a Dbf file and I want to full join two query in C# console application. But It seems that Full Join is not supported in Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0. I get the Following error when I run the query.

> IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

Here are the Table Details and the desired query Behaviour.

> Purchase and Sales transactions are stored in the Table Mtrans.DBF. And the field It_type is used to distinguish between Purchase transaction and Sales Transaction.I want to combine both sales and Purchase quantities of an item in a single row.

But the query runs smooth without any error if i use left or inner or right join instead of Full join. Please Help me in this. I request the experts here to throw some lights on if there are any workaround for this error.

Here is my Query EXpresision

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select purtran.it_name,purtran.it_code,
purtran.purcqnty,purtran.puruqnty,saltran.cqnty,
saltran.uqnty,saltran.avalue from 
(select first(it_name) as    
it_name,mtrans.it_code,sum(cqnty) as purcqnty,sum(uqnty)
as puruqnty 
from mtrans 
where date >=#" + fdt + "# and 
date <=#" + tdt + "# and  (voucher is null  or len(voucher) =0)
 and it_type = '01' 
group by it_code) as purtran
full join
(select it_code,sum(cqnty) as cqnty,
sum(uqnty) as uqnty,sum(avalue) as avalue,first(tp1) as tp1 
from mtrans 
where date >=#" + fdt + "# and date <=#" + tdt + "# 
and (voucher is null or len(voucher) = 0) and 
it_type = '02' group by it_code)
saltran  
on saltran.it_code = purtran.it_code ", con);
da.Fill(dt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Access does not support FULL JOIN. You need to do a LEFT JOIN and combine the results using UNION ALL with a RIGHT JOIN. See this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-full-joins.htm) .

Comment: Thank You So much Ron Tornambe !! It helped So much!! Your "Union All" Suggestion worked out so well!